# the content of a DataGridViewCell are not displayed if its length is greater than 4608

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have found out that if a DataGridViewCell's content is greater than 4608 characters in length, its contents are not displayed on screen.

[image: DataGridView test]

I would like to display at least the first few characters.
How could I manage to do that?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to handle `CellFormatting` event of grid and take substring of values which are too long:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null)
        return;
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;
    // only for 2nd column
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 1)
        return;
    var txt = e.Value.ToString();
    if (txt.Length > 4608)
    {
        e.Value = txt.Substring(0, 4608);
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the content of a DataGridViewCell are not displayed if its length is greater than 4608

This definitely **is not true**, as you may see:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Test
    {
        class Foo
        {
            public int Length { get { return Text != null ? Text.Length : 0; } }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var dataSet = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(n => new Foo { Text = new string('A', n) }).ToList();
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            dg.DataSource = dataSet;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

so there must be some problem in your code.